# Durandal: compositionComplete called too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I am trying to apply bootstrap popover to a DOM element. I apply the popoover immediately the view is ready -`popover('show'` I apply it in the compositionComplete method of bootstrap and realize that the element is not property centered horizontally. It is pushed to the right a little too much.

If I remove the popover('show') and only makes it visible when on hover, all works well. If I leave the popover'show' and force the popover to apply after 1sec, all works fine. It therefore seems as the viewattached is called too early, hence the popover calculations of the position are incorrect. How can I fix this please.

Below is my method

```
function compositionComplete(view, parent) {
   //setTimeout(function() {     --works if I all this
            $(element).popover({
                placement: 'bottom',
                //trigger: 'hover',
                template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
                content: 'This is the content',
                title: 'Start here',
            }).popover('show');
       //, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: what causes the $(element) in question to be rendered?  Perhaps it's something asyncronous?   What if you add to the view: `<div id='test1'>test</div>` and then use `$('#test1').popover...` ?

Comment: The element is aleady present when the page loads. it is basically part of a div.